# Drupal7 Delete Page

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

In Drupal on all pages there is a tab to view or edit node. Is there a module or configuration option through which we can add delete option there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a module that does that (it's probably too minor an action to warrant its own stand alone module), but you can add the following lines to an existing custom module or create a new one:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/delete']['context'] = MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE;
}
```

That will hoist the delete link out of the inline actions and make it available as a tab on node pages for users with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: I just added this in my live website. ;)

Comment: Thank You Clive, but I don't know how to create a custom module. Can I add this in any existing contributed or system module.

Comment: I wouldn't do that to be honest, hacking core/contrib modules is never a good idea. Take a quick look at [Creating Drupal 7.x modules](http://drupal.org/node/361112) to get yourself started on writing a module. You only need two files in your case, an .info file and a .module. The .module will have the above code in it (with MYMODULE replaced with the name of your module) and there's instructions for the .info file on the link I posted